# Combine multiple rows into one in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table like this and i need to combine all of them into a `distinct` row using sum.

```
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-------+
| users | ref | add  | sub  | mul  | marks |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-------+
| u1    |  20 | 4521 |      |      |    20 |
| u1    |  20 | 4522 |      |      |    80 |
| u1    |  20 | 4523 |      |      |    60 |
| u1    |  20 |      | 8565 |      |    70 |
| u1    |  20 |      | 8566 |      |    30 |
| u1    |  20 |      |      | 5135 |    10 |
| u2    |  15 | 4521 |      |      |    20 |
| u2    |  15 | 4522 |      |      |    20 |
| u2    |  15 |      | 6253 |      |    30 |
| u3    |  20 | 5236 |      |      |    40 |
| u3    |  20 |      | 4523 |      |    50 |
| u3    |  20 |      | 4524 |      |     5 |
| u3    |  20 |      | 4525 |      |    30 |
| u3    |  20 |      |      | 5135 |    20 |
+-------+-----+------+------+------+-------+
```

Something like this. Is it possible? I tried `group by` and didn't get this result.

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| users | ref | add | sub | mul | total |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
| u1    |  20 |   3 |   2 | 1   |   270 |
| u2    |  15 |   2 |   1 | n/a |    70 |
| u3    |  20 |   1 |   3 | 1   |   145 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Show us your attempt, It should have worked

Comment: Is that not a count rather than a sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should use `group by` to aggregate:

```
select users, ref,
  count(`add`) `add`,
  count(sub) sub,
  count(mul) mul,
  sum(marks) total
from tablename
group by users, ref
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u2j8zqPWunW2f2NH65qTP7/0).
Results:

```
| users | ref | add | sub | mul | total |
| ----- | --- | --- | --- | --- | ----- |
| u1    | 20  | 3   | 2   | 1   | 270   |
| u2    | 15  | 2   | 1   | 0   | 70    |
| u3    | 20  | 1   | 3   | 1   | 145   |
```